# Is it possible to create DataRelation 1:1 in c#?

Tags: c#, database, foreign-keys, datarelation

In my app I use ORM Designer which supports only 1:1 relation. I have Items, Products, Shipping tables: Item has ProductId and ShippingId attributes which are foreign keys.

I need to upload data from xml file into my SQL DB, so I gonna use SqlBulkCopy class and I need to create DataTable objects: itemsTable, productsTable, shippingTable to load data from xml into them.

So, do I need to create DataRelations: ItemsProducts and ItemsShipping? If so, itemsTable would contain productsTable and shippingTable?

Thanks!

**Edits:**

And is it possible to write to server the content from 3 dataTables simultaneously?

Comment: That sounds like it's `1:*` relationships, not `1:1`.  An actual one-to-one would mean that each Item has exactly one ProductId, and each Product has exactly one ItemId.  So you need one product for each item.

Comment: yes, it is: item just accumulates shiping, product + other details, so 1 item has exactly 1 product and 1 shipping)

Comment: Yes, but one product belongs to more than one item, I assume.

Comment: it should be so, but I use ORM Designer and it only supports one to one relationship

Comment: I'm sorry, but if it only supports one to one, then it's the most poorly designed ORM tool I've *ever* run across.  How do you do a receipt with 5 products on it?  How do you associate it with a customer? Does every receipt require you to create a new customer and new products?  Ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it's entirely possible to have a one-to-many relationship in a `.dbml` file.  See the screenshot below, which is simply the properties sidebar you can get to by right-clicking on an association and choosing "Properties".

[image]

Comment: I'll note that the "Parent" relationship shows `1:1-*`, which is the same as saying `1:*`, and *not at all* like saying `1:1`.

Comment: where can I find this window menu?

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi - Just double-click on the association.

Comment: You mean in Visual Studio ProjectName.dbml designer file? I used Linq to Sql Model first approach to autogenerate classes and I remember that on msdn I've read that it doesn't support 1:*. I think You are talking about EF model first, right?

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi - No, I meant in ORM Designer.  That's where I screen-capped the image from.  I didn't try to import that file into Visual Studio.

Comment: I use VS2012, when I double click the association in designer the window appeares, but there are no options to choose

Comment: So you're using the built-in DBML editor and not [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/)?  That changes everything...

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi - Ok, I've revised the answer.  You should be clearer about things like that in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SqlBulkCopy`, you have to do it using one table/entity at a time. It will work if the entities already have the foreign key values. BTW I created a wrapper object for `SqlBulkCopy` that can do a bulk insert for a collection of objects.

It may help you, you can find it here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354094/Bulk-Insert-in-NET-applications-Part-1

Comment: so, there is no way to WriteToServer 3 tables simultaneously?